# htaccess regex Keep spiderbots outside

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get this part of the htaccess working :

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(360Spider|acoon|ahrefs|aihit|altushost|amazon|archive|airjordanin|applecreek|baidu|bezeqint|bilbo|bork|botje|butterfly|buy) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(catchbot|career|cloud-ips|coach|contabo|corbina) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(dataprovider|digext|discobot|dotbot|ec2|edisterBot|energis|ephorus|exabot|exigen|ezooms|fastlink|genieo|huaweiSymantecSpider) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(iguana|ileadz|ipxserver|jaunty|jadynave|jikespider|keywordspy|kimsufi|kobala|komodiabot|koula|longchamp) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(magpie|majestic12|malas|Media|michael|MJ12bot|modx|mohitseo|MOR306|mulberryoculos) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(nashirnet|ncsa|netwiz|obot|openindex|osso|panscient|pathcom|PeoplePal|piki|presto|purity) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(santrex|scoutjet|shabnet|sistrix|siteexplorer|softlayer|sogou|sosospider|Spinn3r|splims|statsbot|survey) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(tangoo|targetdevelopmentdirect|thunderstone|trabajoo|track|trellian|trendictionbot|turnitinBot|TweetmemeBot|ukraine) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(vagabondo|vanekeris|vectranet|webcijfers|wise|yabrowser|yandex|yodao|zh-CN) [NC]

# ISSUE 403 / SERVE ERRORDOCUMENT
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

---

Tried also without ^ at the beginning and $ at the end
but the bots are still coming, regarding to my statistics in php
Tried also instead of HTTP_USER_AGENT the Referer , the Host and the FORWARDED, and in numbers the remote_address.

Any help ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are attempting to do?  It seems from your closing statement that you want to filter our bots - however the Error message is for what exactly?

Comment: The source ( haven't saved the address ) made the comment line: # ISSUE 403 / SERVE ERRORDOCUMENT and the ending line : RewriteRule . - [F,L], so the bots should get this errordocument instead of a real webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The rule looks good so far, though I would change two things.

- exclude `robots.txt` from the rule, because many of these adhere to the [Robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). Add

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$
  ```

  and then fill the `robots.txt` with a meaningful set of rules. If you want to exclude all robots

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /
  ```
- change `.` to `^`, because the home page is not yet included in this rule

  ```
  RewriteRule ^ - [F]
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Olaf Dietsche, for your answer. Because I don't understand what is going on, could you explain how and why : the value where to look in, is for instance %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}, the value to look for is for instance 360Spider and so on. I would have thought : take 360 spider as a part of a string, look in the http user agent and start from the beginning ..... instead the start of the beginnen wich is '^' is used before the searchvalue ? The same for the ending symbol '$'

Comment: @DocMartin Yes, this is how it works and it does so. When I use this rule in my test environment, I get a 403 forbidden response status code. This doesn't prevent the bots from coming back. Although I get a 403 response, I can request the same page as long and as many times as I like.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf Dietsche, for your answer. But how to prevent they get any page but 403 or something else ? Some spiders do 120 pages a minute, including MySQL content is a lot of resources :-(

Comment: @DocMartin Why do you think, this doesn't work? Look into the access.log, there you should see the requests and the `403` response.

Comment: @DocMartin This is unusual. Most web hosters don't provide access to `error.log`, but `access.log` is usually available. Anyway, do you have other rules in the htaccess file or do you have htaccess files in other directories? This could be a reason for this rule not working.